# How to exacute a .py in another.py script?

Tags: python

Hello a newbie here needing some help...

So I want to execute a .py in the middle of another script. To be more specific inside the script below (`script1.py)`:

```
password = raw_input("Type in a password: ")
password2 = raw_input("Password: ")
if password == password2:
   GPIO.output(36,1)
else:
   GPIO.output(40,1
```

I want to add and execute `scritp2.py` after 'if password == password2:'

How can this be achieved? (Thank you in advance)

Comment: In Python 2, there's a function called `execfile`. Take a look at that...

Answer (score 2):

The normal way would be to have your code inside a function scritp2.py. Then with scritp2.py inside the same directory as your original script you inside you can call this function after importing:

```
import scritp2
if password1==password2:
    scritp2.func()
```